# Fitting segmented regression model with multiple predictors in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to fit a segmented regression model using the "segmented" package in R. I understand the basic principals behind it but I think that I'm hitting a coding wall. I would like to fit the following model.

lin.mod.1<-lm(WTM~DCA+Armored)
seg.mod.1<-segmented(lin.mod.1,seg.Z=~DCA+Armored,psi=???)

WTM and DCA are continuous variables. DCA is a proportion, running from 1 to 0. I would guess that the break point of DCA is 0.4. Armored is a 0/1 factor indicating whether or not a sample was taken at and armored site. Where I am running into trouble is in the values of psi. Do I suppose I need to pick a break point for Armored, buts its a factor... so would it just be 1? I have been successful fitting segmented model with one predictor so I think I may be making a syntax/coding error.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Did you try using NA for psi and let segmented choose the initial value? seg.mod.1<-segmented(lin.mod.1,seg.Z=~DCA+Armored,psi=list(DCA=NA,Armored=NA))